# When would one use “Zahl” and when “Anzahl”?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I understand that *Zahl* represents a single number or figure and can be used in statements like ([from Pons](http://en.pons.com/translate?q=zahl&l=deen&in=&lf=de)):

> Zahl der Arbeitslosen
>
> die Zahl der Besucher
>
> Die tatsächliche Zahl der Ebola-Fälle sei in Liberia wahrscheinlich zweieinhalb Mal höher als die offiziell genannte, erläuterte Aylward.

The third example is an excerpt from a news article about Ebola that also used *Zahl,* but to me, it seems completely and utterly interchangeable with *Anzahl.* Would that be right or are there certain situations where one would use one over the other?

The example in Pons for *Anzahl* is:

> Anzahl getöteter Personen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are referring to the cardinality¹ of something, i.e., to a count of something, *Anzahl* and *Zahl* can indeed be used interchangeably. This applies to all your examples, as they refer to the count of people.

However, there are cases, where you cannot use both:

- If you are referring to a number as a mathematical object or its representation, you can only use *Zahl:*

  > Die Zahl 42 wird gerne als Beispiel für irgendeine Zahl verwendet.
  >
  > Auf dem Bildschirm blinkte die Zahl 42 auf.

  It may also help that you cannot use *Anzahl* if the number in question is not a [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) or you can replace it by a non-natural number. For example, only *Zahl* can be used to refer to −2, ¾ or √2 in any context.
- In some fossilised expressions, figures of speech, etc., you can only use *Zahl* (at least partly due to the above), e.g., *schwarze Zahlen schreiben, in großer Zahl, an der Zahl.*

---

¹ This includes infinite cardinalities and thus both the following examples are correct:

> Die Anzahl der Farben des Regenbogens ist unendlich, nicht sieben.
>   Die Zahl der Farben des Regenbogens ist unendlich, nicht sieben.

Answer (score 8):

According to [this source](http://www.korrekturen.de/forum.pl/md/read/id/27805/sbj/zahl-oder-anzahl/) the Duden Volume 9 "Richtiges und gutes Deutsch" explains:

> **Anzahl/Zahl:** Die alte Unterscheidung, dass Zahl die Gesamtzahl, die Gesamtmenge ausdrückt, Anzahl dagegen einen Teil davon, ist auch im heutigen Sprachgebrauch noch nicht verloren gegangen und sollte überall da beachtet werden, wo es auf eine präzise Aussage ankommt: Die Zahl der Zugezogenen liegt bei ungefähr 500 Personen, darunter eine erhebliche Anzahl Studenten. In der Alltagssprache werden beide Wörter häufig gleichbedeutend gebraucht.

I don't have this book available to check it myself.

So you should prefer "Zahl" for the size of a whole set and use "Anzahl" for the size of a subset, but in everyday life both words are often used as synonyms.

Your example "die Anzahl getöteter Personen" might be taken from a news message about a terrorist attack, where the group of killed people would be a subset of all victims (including injured people). So using "Anzahl" here fits to the Duden recommendation.

Comment: Also ist – oder war – die _Anzahl_ gewissermaßen die _Zahl_ vom _Anteil_.

Comment: Sehr interessant. Ich will niemandem es nehmen, gutes altes Deutsch zu pflegen, die Behauptung, dass diese Unterscheidung noch "im heutigen Sprachgebrauch" sei halte ich aber seitens des Duden für gewagt...

Answer (score 1):

They’re interchangeable with a slight amendment in the corresponding sentence. Your four examples would become:

> Anzahl (von) Arbeitslose(n)
>
> die Anzahl (der) Besucher
>
> Die tatsächliche Anzahl (der) Ebola-Fälle [...]
>
> Zahl der getöteten Personen

After *Zahl* an article necessarily has to follow. That’s not the case for *Anzahl;* the article there usually is optional. That’s because, e.g., *Die Zahl großer Menschen* would address the number *(Zahl)* that is owned by tall people.

Furthermore you must use another case for the nouns. After *Zahl* you have to use nominative. After *Anzahl* you go either with the nominative again or with the accusative (depends on the article and on whether you use one or not).

Comment: While you are correct that using *Zahl* without a following article may be ambiguous, it is generally accepted to use *Zahl* without an article following. Even the Duden uses this in the majority [its examples](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zahl#Bedeutung3).

Comment: @peasant I don't see how adding an article makes it less ambiguous: "die Zahl der großen Menschen" sounds just as ambiguous to me as "die Zahl großer Menschen".

Answer (score -1):

An --> at --> attached to, close to, part of

Examples:
Anzug
Antrag

Zahl = Number --> Used if you just want to count
Anzahl similar to Amount --> Used if you want to identify a share

Teil = part --> A door is part of a car.
Anteil = share (of) / amount --> The amount of weight the doors contribute to the cars weight is substantial.

Comment: Can you please format your answer and check the spelling? Right now, I can only guess what some sentences mean and where they begin.