# What is the difference between "Lagenzahl" and "Lagenanzahl"?

Tags: usage, spelling, compound, technical-terminology, business-correspondence

In Electronics, what is the difference between *Lagenzahl* and *Lagenanzahl*? *Lagenzahl* has been seen in proposals and *Lagenanzahl* in product descriptions. Such terms are used by people in the industry.

Comment: Lagenanzahl = Anzahl der Lagen (e.g. layers of a printed circuit board). I've never heard "Laganzahl" in electronics. Context or examples?

Comment: I am not an expert in Electronics and I never heard "Laganzahl". I googled it (with quotation marks) and got 72 results, most of them related to finance/economy/statistics. From the context it seems a compositum made of "Lagan" (whatever that is) and "Zahl" (figure), rather than "Lag" (whatever that is) and "Anzahl" (amount). Does "Laganzahl" occur often in your case? Or maybe it is just a misspelling of "Lagenanzahl" (amount of layers)?

Comment: We probably need more **context** to figure out any differences. I believe those two terms are not related.

Comment: I was about to write a detailed answer, but the question was closed. So I will just point to the Wikipedia article on [Fugenlaut](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut) and point out that Germany as spoken in Germany, Austria and Switzerland often differs a lot in these details. Apart from the excellent explanation by Carsten S (misspelling), there is a slight chance that it's actually a regional variation.

Comment: @HansAdler, I know, I can tell you that these words are being used close to the border of Germany with The Netherlands. Any ideas for an answer?

Comment: @ondrums you've pointed out; I've changed the question accordingly.

Comment: @dirkt consider the word Lagenzahl, instead.

Comment: So your question boils down to the difference between _Zahl_ and _Anzahl_. http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17784/when-would-one-use-zahl-and-when-anzahl

Comment: Please clarify both "industry" and "proposals". Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you meant *Lagenzahl*. If so, then there is no difference; *Zahl* is often used synonymously with *Anzahl*, which is slightly more precise.

Of course, I may be completely wrong and it's a constant named by some Monsieur Lagan.

Comment: Thanks for that. I mean both, actually. The two are being used differently.

Comment: It's not _Laganzahl_ BTW.